# Remove all footers from Google Group listserv

Tags: google-groups

> You received this message because you are subscribed to the Google Groups "examplelist" group.
>
> To unsubscribe from this group and stop receiving emails from it, send an email to examplelist+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com.
>
> For more options, visit https://groups.google.com/groups/opt_out.

I've removed all other footers from my business Google Group but am left with this one. Is there any way to remove it? In my particular use case, no one from outside the organization can subscribe, so no one is unsubscribing and the chance of spam is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try unchecking this?

But this is only available in paid G Suite accounts. For Google Groups on a free account, unfortunately, there is no option to remove it.

[image]

Comment: yes that didn't affect the quoted line—perhaps it removed some additional text?

Comment: Removing both checkmarks there takes everything off for me, see https://i.imgur.com/YYwtwaz.gif. Maybe post a screenshot

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer with help from @Yisroel Tech

Business (not regular) users have that checkbox option to uncheck "Include Default Groups Footer" and that will remove all footers *when sent to subscribers in the same domain*

However, when **someone outside the domain is subscribed** (e.g., a forwarding address to get that message into Slack), the footer will display the unsubscribe line:

> To unsubscribe from this group and stop receiving emails from it, send an email to examplelist+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com.

My understanding is that [this is for compliance](https://support.google.com/a/thread/6273833?hl=en&msgid=7015556) with the 2004 CAN-SPAM Act and GDPR regulations.

Answer (score 2):

One hacky way I found around @Wolf's issue, is to add the external email address as the recipient of another group.  That way, the initial group doesn't think it's sending externally, so it doesn't trigger the message.

In my case, I want emails that are sent to notifications@example.com to get forwarded to my cell phone (mobile), but without the footer.

Where the emails are sent to:
notifications@example.com
Member:  externalalias@example.com

create intermediate "group":
externalalias@example.com
Member:  cellphonenumber@tmomail.net

So far, this is working for me with a legacy "free" Google Apps account.

Answer (score 2):

You should not add cellphonenumber@tmomail.net as a member. You should go to the admin panel of Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) and go to Apps --> Google Workspace --> Gmail --> Routing --> Add a new routing

And then add more recipients

Comment: This is the way, you can forward the message to a new email and still let it route to the group using "Email forwarding using recipient address map"